# Rails facebook app returns 422 " the change u wanted was rejected" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth

My facebook is just approved today. However,when I clicked on "Go to app", it returns Rail 422 " The change you wanted was rejected. error" I set my Canvas URL to my site url and I am using Omniauth, so I am just wondering what did I miss.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try removing

```
protect_from_forgery
```

In the application_controller, or

```
# you can disable csrf protection on controller-by-controller basis:
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
```

Facebook uses signed_request that you can decode and use to verify that the request actually comes from facebook, so protect_from_forgery is unnecessary for applications that are accessible through the facebook canvas only.

More here: [Canvas Authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/canvas) & [ActionController::RequestForgeryProtection](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection.html)

Answer (score 0):

**Facebook's omniauth error "the change you wanted was rejected"**
might appear because of your validations set in the model. I had to refactor my validation for users having one unique email, which wasn't working when a user would try to facebook login with the same email.

Look at your logs. `heroku logs -t`