# Facebook login with OmniAuth Error Change was Rejected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, omniauth

I was able to set up my Facebook and Twitter Login using Omniauth http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth my Rails app. My login works perfectly on my computer (I tested both on production and development) and I did not detect a problem until someone e-mailed me this problem when he tried to sign in with Facebook:

`The change you wanted was rejected.
Maybe you tried to change something you didn't have access to.`

It turns out that no one else can sign in or create an account through FB or Twitter besides me on my development computer.

From other solutions, I removed `protect_from_forgery` and added `skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token` to my application_controller.rb, but I'm still getting that same problem.

I'm hosting my app on Heroku.

Does anyone know what's going on? Let me know if you guys need any additional info.

Comment: Sounds like you're having the same issue as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621514/rails-facebook-app-returns-422-the-change-u-wanted-was-rejected-error).

Comment: @kaptron Yes, I saw that solution and followed it. It didn't do anything for me.

Comment: Found my problem. It was a simple name validation that was throwing that error.

Comment: ^ That totally was my problem as well.  Everyone should make sure that they check their production logs / heroku logs to see if it really is an Omniauth problem.  The problem is also that the 422 isn't noticeably a 422 until you look at the validation errors in the logs.