# Getting ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken) error for devise sign in and sign up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise

I know there are so many posts related to this error but still...

I am getting following error while sign in / sign up for devise. (2 days back it is working fine able to sing in / up.)

```
Feb 02 22:16:12 myapp app/web.1:  Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML 
Feb 02 22:16:12 myapp app/web.1:    Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"d0R529vsmCovMKZk1RC9ioxfVHivvVGKxPFvNkEUqVId08qPMDRN0lu9yULIAaTJR+p1oOXyg8QsE+PdZx4CHg==", "user"=>{"app_name"=>"tempo", "email"=>"xyz@vision.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"submit"} 
Feb 02 22:16:12 myapp app/web.1:  Can't verify CSRF token authenticity 
Feb 02 22:16:12 myapp app/web.1:  ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken): 
Feb 02 22:16:12 myapp app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:181:in `handle_unverified_request' 
Feb 02 22:16:12 myapp app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:209:in `handle_unverified_request' 
Feb 02 22:16:12 myapp app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/devise-3.5.6/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb:257:in `handle_unverified_request' 
Feb 02 22:16:12 myapp app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:204:in `verify_authenticity_token'
```

I am getting this error for the production application which is hosted on the Heroku.

I have a staging app (Which is also hosted on the heroku and have same code base) and it is working fine.

I am able to login and sign up on it.

I have referred the following links but getting the same issue

[Rails facebook app returns 422 " the change u wanted was rejected" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621514/rails-facebook-app-returns-422-the-change-u-wanted-was-rejected-error)

[devise user sign_in gives authentication error for CSRF token authenticity token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19861402/devise-user-sign-in-gives-authentication-error-for-csrf-token-authenticity-token)

[rails - "WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity" for json devise requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9362910/rails-warning-cant-verify-csrf-token-authenticity-for-json-devise-requests)

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2734

I am using rails 4 for the same.

**EDIT**

I have tired following solutions

- Removed `protect_from_forgery` from the application controller
- Checked `csrf_meta_tags` present or not in the layout and it is present.
- Also checked `authenticity_token` from the form. You can find my submitted form details in the log trace.
- Added following in application controller

  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, if: :devise_controller?

Comment: It is the network issue. Our network administrator made few changes in the firewall that's why it caused the issue. It also affect on the other sites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the network issue. Our network administrator made few changes in the firewall that's why it caused the issue. It also affect on the other sites

Comment: Can you elaborate? It would be very helpful for me and a lot of people that are experiencing the same issue

Comment: how to reslove this???

Comment: kindly explain what happens. we have an identical issue. I don't change any of my code. then suddenly got an error.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a couple of things...

**1. You forgot to add the `<%= csrf_meta_tags %>` inside your layout file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Sample</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>
  <body>  
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

**2. You need to set protect_from_forgery to the following:**

Simply declaring protect_from_forgery without a :with argument will utilize :null_session by default:

```
protect_from_forgery # Same as above
```

**3. The author of Devise suggests disabling protect_from_forgery on the particular controller action that's raising this exception:**

```
# app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => :create
end
```

**4. You need to add the following line to your form**

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token -%>
```

Comment: I already have  `csrf_meta_tags` in my layout and also have `protect_from_forgery` in my application controller.

Comment: are you using a `:with` along with protect_from_forgery?

Comment: I have tried this way `skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, if: :devise_controller?` but getting same error

Comment: does your form have a hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token? (edited answer)

Comment: No, But I am using form_for which provides the by default `hidden field` for the authenticity_token.

Comment: I have updated my question along with log trace. Please have a look

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Finally debugged the issue. It is the network issue. Our network administrator made few changes in the firewall that's why it caused the issue. It also affect on the other sites. :)

Comment: @shrikant1712 can you explain what happen to your network?